# Just another ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error message, however I cannot find any solution that works for me

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, ado.net

I am using Visual Studio 2017.  Oracle is version 11 but I am not sure about the sub-version of Oracle.

I created two new tables in Oracle.  I granted them Select, Update, Insert and Delete with this command:

```
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT on "ADMIN"."MYTABLE" to "APP";
```

All of the existing tables use at least the exact same privileges and I can query them through entity framework until the cow come home without any problems. It is just my new tables.

My context file looks like this:

```
public class OracleContext : DbContext
{
    public OracleContext() : base("name=OracleConnection") {}

    public DbSet<MyTable> myTable { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("ADMIN");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().ToTable("MYTABLE");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

My table class looks like:

```
[Table("ADMIN.MYTABLE")]
public class MyTable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("ID", TypeName = "NUMBER")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("Name", TypeName = "VARCHAR2")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a map file that looks like this:

```
public class MyTableMap : IMapper
{
    public void Map(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        var en = builder.Entity<MyTable>();

        en.ToTable("ADMIN.MYTABLE");

        en.Property(t => t.ID)
                .HasColumnName("ID")
                .IsRequired();

        en.Property(t => t.NAME)
                .HasColumnName("NAME");
    }
}
```

My entity framework code looks like this:

```
using (var context = new OracleContext())
{
    List<MyTable> myTable = context.MyTable.ToList();
}
```

I new to Oracle.  I come from a SQL Server background but I brought other developers who are Oracle experts in on this and they were also baffled.

Just to see what would happen I used ADO.Net to open a connection and pass a SQL Query string to a command object and return a reader and I get the same error with my new tables, however, I can run a select * query on any of the other tables in the database without any problems.

I can run this query in Oracle's SQL Developer without any problems.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I might be doing wrong.

---

UPDATE (12/15/2020): The problem I am having has to do when I create an "ASP.Net Web Application (.NET Framework)" application.  I started with an app I was developing but then I have created a test application as an "ASP.Net Web Application (.NET Framework)" application and I get the same results.

A "Console App (.New Framework)", however, will work.  Earlier when I got it to work in the Console app I had just assumed that it would work in any type of web app but I was wrong.

I am connection to Oracle using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess vers 19.10.0 app that I downloaded out of NuGet.  Recently I downloaded Dapper to simplify the data access code.  It doesn't matter.  Using ADO.net or Entity Framework will find my tables in a Console app but it cannot find the tables in a Web App.

Comment: can you check in your sql developer by saying "Set role  None" and see if you are still able to select from the table, if not then it means the select access has been granted through a role and you may want select to be granted  directly and not through a role.

Comment: I ran that command and the select command still returns all of the data in the table in SQL Developer.

Comment: One thing I noticed was that after I ran "Set Role None" is if I clicked on a table name, in the Connections window, I got an error message saying that the table was not found.  I closed and reopened SQL Developer to get new session so everything would return back to normal.

Comment: There is rather simple checklist for all this *object - relational* stuff. 1) check which database user is used to connect (note that this is **not** `APP` as from your comment is obvious, that `APP` is a `ROLE`. 2) check which *select statement* is used. (This can be done with some tracing parameters such as show_sql=true or similar; the *best way* is to use the Oracle  10046 trace). If you have both, you may validate in SQL Developer but you must connect with the *aplication user* and use the *exact SQL statement.* Good Luck!

Comment: The names were changed in my example.  I am really not sure what "APP" is.  Like I said I am not an Oracle guy.  I'm a SQL Server guy.  I just know that all in all of the existing tables "APP" is the Grantee.

I used an technique that one of the other developers showed me.  He added code to the OracleContext() class that directed all of the SQL messages to the Output window.  I copied the select statement from that and pasted it into SQL Developer and it runs fine.

Comment: It looks like you need direct access to the object  and not through  a role, try getting direct access to the object.

Comment: @hkandpal - I am not sure what you mean by direct access.  Like I said I am new to Oracle.  I never really did much with schemas in any place I worked before.  99.999% of the places I worked "dbo" was the schema that we used in SQL Server.  And synonyms are a new concept to me.  I kind of thought I was directly accessing the object.

Comment: @hkandpal -  Did you mean for me to use ADO.net, open a connection, pass a SQL query through a command object to that connection and then reading the results in a DataReader object or something like that.  I tried this and I got the exact same error.

Comment: I just created a console app using ADO.net.  I was able to retrieve data from MyTable without any problem.  Now I am going to add entity framework to my console app and see if I can get that working.  If I can then maybe I will have an idea if what I am doing wrong in my application.

Comment: Yesterday I said I created a console app using ADO.net and that worked.  However, I need this running in Entity Framework.  If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: As it turns out it does not matter that I use Entity Framework or not.  ADO.net is acceptable.  But as I added to the Update of the original message, the tables I created cannot be found if I create a Web Application but using the same ADO.Net code in a Console app works fine.

I just need it to work in a Web App.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer to my problem.  I have a Web.Config and a Web.Debug.Config that contains connection strings.  Web.Config has a connection string to the production server.  Web.Debug.Config has a connection string to the development server.

This is just a normal set up.  My problem is that Visual Studio isn't recognizing the transform code in Web.Debug.Config to replace the production connection string with the development connection string ("< connectionStrings xdt:Transform='Replace'>")

I haven't created my tables on the production server and that is the reason for the error.